# problem with configuration manager in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, configurationmanager

I'm trying to get the key that was added to the app settings in web.config file :

```
<add key="ComponentXML" value="~/App_Data/Components.XML"/>
```

and i'm trying to retrieve the value in this manner:

```
           string componentsXMLFile = "ComponentXML";
     ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[componentsXMLFile ]);
```

But it is freaking out:

```
Could not find a part of the path 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\~\App_Data\Components.XML
```

which is not at all part of my project folder, it is referring to something else

how can i solve this ? I'm stuck with this problem from past 3 hours.

Please help me

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Does the code that reads the settings reside in a ASP.NET web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code resides in the asp.net web page and this line did the trick for me.

```
Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[componentsXMLFile]);
```

I found the source of answer from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) after some more googling.

Thanks

Comment: @Subhash i can only accept my own answer only after 2 days from the day i asked the question